# Making do ... while... a function

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

I'm wondering how to do a function in javascript that does the process of the do...while, but I don't know how.

```
    do {
        tableTimes = prompt ("Which number do we do the table times?")
    } while (isNaN(tableTimes) == true);


    do {
        timesByStart = prompt("From which number do we start?")
    } while (isNaN(timesByStart) == true);

    do {
        timesByEnd = prompt("In which number do we end?")
    } while (isNaN(timesByEnd) == true);
```

That's what I have, but I'd like to have something like:

```
    askTheNumber(nameOfTheVariable, Question)
```

How can I do it?? Is it posible?

Comment: could you explain your problem more precisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
function askTheNumber(question) {
  var answer;
  do {
    answer = prompt(question);
  } while (isNaN(answer));
  return answer;
}

var tableTimes=askTheNumber("Which number do we do the table times?");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need only one parameter for such function which is `question`.see code below

```
function askTheNumber(question){
  do {
      var input = prompt(question);
   } while (isNaN(input) == true);
   return input
};


vat timesByStart = askTheNumber("From which number do we start?");
var timesByEnd = askTheNumber("In which number do we end?");
var tableTimes = askTheNumber("In which number do we end?");
```

Comment: perhaps it would be useful if the function returned the value of input..?

Comment: @BillyMoon yeah, i've noticed that miss in same time with you :) Thanks !